# How to insert large number of rows from a datatable to a list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, datatable

I have a situation in C# where I have a Data Table which contains around 8-10k rows.

I need to insert these rows into an object list.  Right now I am doing it one by one but it is obviously taking ages to insert and display.

Is it possible to do this in a faster way?

```
var resultList = aggResults.ExtractRows(row => new ActivitySummaryGrouped
{
    TimeSlot = row.Field<DateTime>("timestamp").ConvertUtcTimeToMountainTime(),
    Product = row.ExtractItemOrDefault(QueryField.Product.ToString(), product),
    Client = row.ExtractItemOrDefault(QueryField.Client.ToString(), client),
    Host = row.ExtractItemOrDefault(QueryField.Host.ToString(), host)

});
```

There are no errors but it is taking a lot of time to insert a large amount of data from Datatable to a List.

We are not using entity framework. We are getting data from elastic search.
I can implement pagination for displaying data but since we need to calculate averages, totals and other calculation etc on total number of datarows present, I cannot use the same.
ExtractRows is an extension method and looks like this:

```
public static List<T> ExtractRows<T>(this DataTable data, Func<DataRow, T> fieldExtractor)
{
   var resultIterator = data.AsEnumerable();
   return resultIterator.Select(fieldExtractor).ToList();
}
```

Front End is Angular JS and we are displaying the data in a grid.

Comment: Normally this would be solved by paging the results. Here on SO you have millions of questions but you will only see 15/30/50 (your choice) per page because of the same reason (performance)

Comment: do you have entity framework? how exactly your are connecting to database other than this way?

Comment: Are `ExtractRows` and `ExtractItemOrDefault` extension methods you wrote? I'm asking this because you might be doing multiple enumerations of your dataset. You should show the rest of your code. How you're filling aggResults and also what ExtractRows is doing perhaps if you wrote it.

Comment: I have updated my question. please have a look.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!
 - You should not display 10k rows!! Do all calculations separately from displaying! It is the display part that takes the time! Also: Where do you display the data??

Answer (score 2):

There is another way which we called the disconnected architecture of ADO.NET. Which we use the DataReader, not DataAdapter. When Pull out your object once then you store in a Javascript object. Furthermore, you can populate the stream of data in your javascript object using the JQuery Libraries.